# docker-compose can't connect to docker daemon?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build a docker environment through docker-compose, however it gives errors.

```
$ docker-compose build
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

Docker daemon is running

```
$ sudo systemctl status docker
[sudo] password for mansop:
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2020-02-19 12:07:27 AEDT; 22min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 8972 (dockerd-current)
    Tasks: 22
   Memory: 22.8M
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           ├─8972 /usr/bin/dockerd-current --add-runtime docker-runc=/usr/libexec/docker/docker-runc-current --default-runtime=docker-runc --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd --userland-proxy-path=/usr/l...
           └─8978 /usr/bin/docker-containerd-current -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --start-timeout 2m --state-dir /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containe...
```

Docker installed from centos7 repository:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 1.13.1, build 4ef4b30/1.13.1
```

I tried setting up DOCKER_HOST following the error message but the issue persists:

```
$ echo $DOCKER_HOST
127.0.0.1:2375
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason there were no docker group in my system, my user was not part of docker group and the docker socket file was not under the docker group.

The commands below fixed my issue:

```
sudo useradd docker
usermod aG docker mansop
sudo chown root:docker /var/run/docker.sock
```